# How to use HibernateValidator with Java Modular System and JavaSE

Tags: jpa, bean-validation, java-platform-module-system

I have a very simple JPA project based on eclipselink. All subprojects have module-info files, so they are java modules. And I have a huge problem with Hibernate Validator integration:

> jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.2.v202107160933): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
> Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [TEST_RENT_PU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30014] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.2.v202107160933): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
> Exception Description: The persistence unit specifies validation-mode as "CALLBACK" but a Bean Validation ValidatorFactory could not be initialized. Please refer to the nested exception for details. Please ensure that Bean Validation API and Bean Validation Provider is available in classpath.
> Internal Exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.validation.spi.ValidationProvider: module jakarta.validation does not declare `uses`

without module-info.java file everything works perfectly (all required libraries are added to pom.xml). As you can see I changed validation settings in persistence.xml file to CALLBACK. With AUTO setting bean validation does not work at all. How should I change the project configuration to make Hibernate Validator working in JPMS environment?